# Average waiting time and stationary measure

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have this stochastic matrix:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
        1/3 &1/3 & 1/3\\
        1/4& 1/4 & 1/2
    \end{pmatrix}$$
And I am asked to find the mean waiting time $\tau_{ij}$ to visit state $j$ over times 1, 2,. . . starting from state $i$ at time $0$, $i, j ∈ S$.

I used the formula  $1+\sum_{k\neq j}^{3}p_{ik}\tau_{kj}$ to find the $\tau_{ij}$ for the matrix and kept only the $\tau_{jj}=\begin{pmatrix}
9/2 & 3 & 9/4
\end{pmatrix}$ to then find $\pi_j$ by doing $\frac{1}{\tau_{jj}}=\begin{pmatrix}
2/9 & 1/3 & 4/9
\end{pmatrix}$.

Is this the correct way to do it?